# Parameters in Object Serialization

Tags: java

I have a Java class implemented `Serializable` interface and this class having two property objects and these two property objects are serialized or not?

Comment: can you post your Java Class and with two property objects?

Comment: @Dasthagiri Please add your java code.

Comment: You can refer the java doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

Comment: Only you know if they are Serializable or not.

Answer (score 1):

They will be serialized unless they have the transient modifier or are non-serializable objects themselves. If there are non-serializable non-transient objects, you will be unable to serialize the instance of your class as it will throw a NotSerializableException.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the fields are serialized along with the class, unless they're `static` or `transient`.

The types of the fields themselves must be serializable, or the exception `java.io.NotSerializableException` will be thrown when you attempt to serialize the object.